# Getting a "couldn't connect to server" error on getblockchaininfo

Tags: bitcoin-core

When I give the following command I get an error after a LONG lag (maybe 15-20 minutes):

```
~: bitcoin-cli getblockchaininfo
error: couldn't connect to server
```

Why?

Answer (score -1):

Are you doing that remotely? if so please make sure that your port is open.

```
sudo ufw allow 8333
```

Also can you provide us with the last a few lines of debug.log file.